# Is there a way to make this code more computationally efficient?

Tags: r, function

I have a problem with this code I made in `R`. I apologize that the names of the variables are not in English, it is not my first language. Here's the code in question:

```
nucleo <- function(theta,n,k){
  producto <- function(theta,n){
log_R <- 0
for (ii in 1:n){
  r <- theta + ii - 1 
  log_R <- log_R + log(r)
}
return(log_R)
}
sd_K <- function(theta,n){
  R <- 0 
  for (ii in 2:n){
    r <- (theta*(ii-1))/((theta + ii - 1)^2)
    R <- R + r
  }
return(sqrt(R))
}
  #res <- ((theta^(k-1))/(producto(theta,n))) * sd_K(theta,n)
  logres <- (k-1)*log(theta) - producto(theta,n) + log(sd_K(theta,n))
  #logres <-   - producto(theta,n)
  #logres <- log(res)
  return(logres)
}
```

I have tried to graph the function for different values of `n` and `k`. The function behaves "nicely" as long as `n <= 187`. I assume it has to do with the `producto` function within the `nucleo` function, because of that I tried using logarithms since they're more computationally efficient than working with products or divisions. But I still encounter the same problem. Is there a way I can make my code more efficient so that it doesn't crash when I use a number bigger that 187 for the `n` variable?

Comment: Hello Andres! Welcome! you might want to check out Code Review! Their speciality is reviewing working code! :-)

Comment: I try running your code, and `nucleo(10, 1870, 10)` works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry my fault, I wasn´t that specific. The problem that I have is that when I try to graph the function for bigger valuer of n the function just goes to 0, if I use n = 185 the graphs look nice; but when I try graph for n = 190 the function instantly goes to 0, as in the only thing that appears in the graph is a line at the the 0 axis

Comment: Can you give some example code? For the actual problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code works well for me even for large `n`.

I can only suggest using vectorization to speed it up:

```
producto = function(theta,n){
  return(sum(log(theta + (1:n) - 1)))
}

sd_K = function(theta,n){
  return(sqrt(theta*sum((1:(n-1))/((theta + 1:(n-1))^2))))
}
```

Comment: Yes it runs fine, I think it was my fault for not being that specific. The problem that I have is that when I try to graph the function for bigger valuer of n the function just goes to 0, if I use n = 185 the graphs look nice; but when I try graph for n = 190 the function instantly goes to 0, as in the only thing that appears in the graph is a line at the the 0 axis